# Spacy nlp.vocab.prune_vectors() raises Warning: Unnamed vectors

Tags: python, vector, nlp, spacy

When pruning vectors in spaCy I'm getting "Warning: Unnamed vectors -- this won't allow multiple vectors models to be loaded. (Shape: (20000, 300))":

```
import spacy  # I'm running 2.0.12
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

nlp.vocab.vectors.name
# Output:
'en_core_web_lg.vectors'

nlp.vocab.vectors.n_keys
# Output:
684830
len(nlp.vocab.vectors)
# Output:
684831

n_vectors = 20000  # number of vectors to keep
removed_words = nlp.vocab.prune_vectors(n_vectors)
# Output:
# Warning: Unnamed vectors -- this won't allow multiple vectors models to be loaded. (Shape: (20000, 300))

nlp.vocab.vectors.name
# Output:
'spacy_pretrained_vectors'

nlp.vocab.vectors.n_keys
# Output:
684755
len(nlp.vocab.vectors)
# Output:
20000
```

The only place I find the error message in the source code is [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/61ef0739b8cede7bf87076f41fa1a2395ff52da2/spacy/_ml.py#L244-L250).
The source for **.prune_vectors()** is [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/vocab.pyx#L261-L310). I don't see where the two are related, or why **nlp.vocab.vectors.name** changes during the pruning process.

Also don't know how pruning misplaces 75 keys...

Comment: I also have this problem. The only thing that correlates for me is it only happens when I trim too much that I don't get a `removed_vectors`  dict back like you do if you only trim a few vectors off the vector space